# Android canvas game problem

Tags: android, canvas, android-layout

I wrote a game used the android SDK sample lunar lander's template, but I found a bug in the template. Through a number of attempts I can't fix it as I want. So I change the game template to Chris pruett's SpriteMethodTest http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/trunk/SpriteMethodTest  In this template I got some problems.

**Problem**:
In [CanvasTestActivity.java](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/trunk/SpriteMethodTest/src/com/android/spritemethodtest/CanvasTestActivity.java)   **onCreate()** method:
The code initialize the surfaceview using:

mCanvasSurfaceView = new CanvasSurfaceView(this);
...
setContentView(mCanvasSurfaceView);

I want to use layout file to take my surfaceview, so I create a layout file like this:

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<me.codeand.xxx.CanvasSurfaceView
  android:id="@+id/gameview"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

I changed the code in oncreate() method:

mCanvasSurfaceView = (CanvasSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.gameview);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

findViewById always return null! I don't know why ! really need help!

BTW,How to add the admob ads in android app that using :
mCanvasSurfaceView = new CanvasSurfaceView(this);
setContentView(mCanvasSurfaceView);

I can't find any sample in the web :(

Best Regards,
czYang

Comment: 囧!! I just change the order of setContentView(R.layout.main); mCanvasSurfaceView = (CanvasSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.gameview); the problem look like solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure you're calling `setContentView(R.layout.main)` before `findViewById` ?

To add AdMob ads, the easiest way is to create a RelativeLayout, add that to the window with `addContentView` , and add the AdView from admob to the bottom of the relative layout using the Gravity.BOTTOM layout parameter.

Comment: thank you very much! the problem solved :)  To add the Admob ads, I means if I don't use layout to place the view, just create AdView programmatically I have no idea about this.